# Why error from na.omit after running scale in R in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I had asked this question earlier and thought I might post an example that shows why I was seeing the effect, in the event that it might be helpful:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(a=1:10)
x[,a:=scale(a)]
#    [,1]      
# 1: -1.4863011
# 2: -1.1560120
# 3: -0.8257228
# 4: -0.4954337
# 5: -0.1651446
# 6:  0.1651446
# 7:  0.4954337
# 8:  0.8257228
# 9:  1.1560120
#10:  1.4863011
na.omit(x)
Error in `[.data.table`(object, !omit) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list     of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if     you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.
```

The reason seems to be that `scale` does not return a `vector` and `data.table` did not complain.  Doing `x[,a:=as.vector(scale(a))]` instead appears to fix the issue. Have I missed something in the documentation?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to post a bug report for `data.table` to the wrong forum. Perhaps you should post it to http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/datatable-help

Comment: yes, that was suggested before. i was actually just posting it here in case other users encountered the same problem so they could avoid spending a ton of time digging through code as i did.

Comment: @Alex, you might reword this as a question.   Then provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question (I edited slightly). It should either be a warning, or `data.table` could coerce the 1 column `matrix` to a vector automatically, since I guess `scale` in the way you showed is a common task and natural to do like that. The `na.omit` aspect is one way of revealing the issue, but there are probably other ways since the root cause is further up as you nicely showed.

Bug report filed, thanks :

[Bug#2333 `:=` is able to create a "matrix" column, but "matrix" columns are invalid](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2333&group_id=240&atid=975)

---

**Update**: Root cause is now fixed in v1.8.3. A 1 column matrix is silently treated as vector. A matrix with 2 or more columns gives a warning.